# Clear-Site-Data header on logout clears from cache only the page logged out from

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-applications, webforms, clear-site-data

In my webform application on logout I call

```
public void Logout()
{
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("AUTH") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30) });
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Clear-Site-Data", "\"*\"");
}
```

However only the **aspx** page I logged out from clears from cache, the rest of the **aspx** pages are still cached.
I have below in **Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
   Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
}
```

How do I get all pages clear from cache at logout?